# Where can I find the strongest armor in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

Where can I find the strongest armor in Fallout 3?

Comment: Well the *best* armor is avoid getting shot. :)

Comment: imo, the best and most game breaking armor in fallout 3 is the chinese stealth armor.  You can punch an super mutant master in the face and he still wouldn't see you while wearing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in Fallout is a trade off. I believe the best armor I got though was the winterized armor found in the Alaska simulation.

Comment: i already have that armor

Comment: @cool without any expansions I believe the Power Armor is the most powerful, but I have yet to complete whatever quest you have to do to equip it.

Comment: @coolcrazy12: Assuming you're talking about damage resistance/reduction, the winterized armor is good, but there is still better in the Fallout 3 world. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 24):

Beneath [Fort Constantine](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fort_Constantine) you can access "Bomb Storage" (using a key from Dukov, Ted Strayer, or any of the others from the "You Gotta' Shoot Em' In The Head" quest) and pick up the [T-51b Power Armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/T-51b_power_armor_(Fallout_3)) - with +50 damage reduction, more than any other armor in the game. The [winterized armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Winterized_T-51b_power_armor) mentioned in another answer only has +45 DR.

There's only one of it in the world. I successfully completed the "You Gotta' Shoot Em' In The Head" quest during one character build and upon entering the room found the armor had been taken, so keep that in mind when you play through other quests.

Comment: This should be the actual accepted answer then.

Comment: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Enclave_Hellfire_Armor#Armor_Comparison

Comment: The good thing about the Winterized power armour is it never goes down from full condition. The T-51b will become damaged over time and since it's the only suit of its kind it can't be easily repaired

Answer (score 2):

In terms of DR, it's a tie between the [T-51b power armor](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/T-51b_power_armor_%28Fallout_3%29) (in [Fort Constantine](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Fort_Constantine); related quest: [You Gotta Shoot 'Em in the Head](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/You_Gotta_Shoot_%27Em_in_the_Head)) and the [Enclave Hellfire armor](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Enclave_Hellfire_armor) (worn by some Enclave Soldiers and [Enclave Hellfire troopers](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Enclave_Hellfire_trooper) if the Broken Steel DLC is installed). Both have 50 DR and 2000 item HP.

> The Hellfire has the same DR as the T-51b power armor and high durability, and boasts the added benefit of +30 Fire resistance and +1 Strength. The only drawback is that the helmet gives a penalty to Charisma, while the T-51b's does the exact opposite.
>
> However, the Hellfire can be repaired with other Hellfire armors, whereas the unique T-51b can only be fixed by merchants. The fact that Enclave troops wearing the Hellfire are somewhat uncommon does reduce the appeal, but that should not discourage.
>
> Note that the armor, as DLC material, cannot be turned in to [Casdin](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Casdin) for his quest.

#### Comparison of Fallout 3 power armors

[image: Comparison of Fallout 3 power armors]

<sup>Source: The Vault wiki, [Enclave Hellfire armor](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Enclave_Hellfire_armor)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The T-51B Winterized Power Armor Earlz was referring to is the strongest armor in the game.  You receive it after completing ALL of the Operation Anchorage content. It is located in the armory you are given access to at the end, before leaving the simulation, as is the Chinese Stealth Armor. You want both of these, and you'll want to grab the Gauss Rifle as well, if you've not already gained access to the alien technology via the Mothership Zeta DLC.  You will not be able to obtain them at any other point in the game.

The T-51B armor is "broken" in that it, essentially, never takes any damage.  Also, the helmet is a stackable item.

If you scroll to the very bottom of the page, in the link below, the first entry in the "Bugs" section explains this fact (which exists in PC, PS3, and XB360 versions).

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Winterized_T-51b_power_armor

Answer (score -2):

Winterized T-51b from Operation: Anchorage is the best- it may have less DR than the normal T-51b, but that all changes when you go into combat. The Winterized T-51b never needs to be repaired, while the normal version breaks down alot. Also, its damage resistance is really high.